# Rails logging to a clean, custom file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've put the following line in my `config/application.rb`:

```
config.logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/app.log")
```

However both `app.log` and `development.log` include all the console "noise".

Is there a way to write on a clean `app.log` file without the noise?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to just limit the amount of information in your log, you'd want to simply [adjust your log level](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html). This is typically done at the environment level, not the application level, as you'd want verbose logs in development, but quieter logs in test/production.

> config.log_level defines the verbosity of the Rails logger. This
>   option defaults to :debug for all environments. The available log
>   levels are: :debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal, and :unknown.

Comment: Thanks but I need the levels. I just need them in separate files.